# JavaFX actions on a separate thread

Tags: java, javafx

I have three classes, the main GUI, a ProgressBarThread, and a ProgressBarDialog.

I am trying to call a new progress bar dialog on a thread when a user preforms an action on the main GUI

```
//Create the new thread when user triggered the action to show the progress bar dialog
ProgressBarThread progressBar = new ProgressBarThread();
progressBar.setStage(stage);
progressBar.setCourseURL(courseURL);

javafx.application.Platform.runLater(progressBar);

//later in the code I try to change the progress, however I get an error (mentioned below)
progressBar.setCurrentProgress("asdasd");
```

ProgressBarThread Class

```
public class ProgressBarThread extends Thread {
    Stage primaryStage;
    String courseURL;
    ProgressBarItemDialog overlay;

    public void setStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    public void setCourseURL(String courseURL) {
        this.courseURL = courseURL;
    }       

    public void setCurrentProgress(String name) {
        overlay.setCurrentProgress(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {    
        //create a new GUI overlay where the primaryStage is the owner
        //this works as intended   
        overlay = new ProgressBarItemDialog(primaryStage, courseURL);
    }
}
```

Inside the ProgressBarItemDialog the function setCurrentProgress()

```
public void setCurrentProgress(String name) {
     headingLabel.setText(name);
}
```

The GUI overlay works as intended, however when I try to update the progress I receive an error when trying to call setCurrentProgress() inside the thread

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: A `NullPointerException` means that an object you were referring to isn't initialized. Paste the whole stacktrace so we can figure out which line it occurs on

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code. For example, `Platform.runLater(progressBar)` does not start a new thread, as your code comment suggests. When you call `progressBar.setCurrentProgress("asdasd")`, the `overlay` in your `progressBar` is still `null`, because the `run()` method that initializes the `overlay` has not run yet. That's why you get the `NullPointerException`. Your approach overall looks very strange. Maybe we can help you better if you try to rephrase the question in terms of _what you are trying to achieve_, instead of trying to fix your current approach.